# Pygame module import error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, frameworks, pygame

I'm still sort of new here so I hope this is ok, but anyway:

I am in the middle of a small project to try and learn a bit of basic game design using python. I have been using Pygame on the latest version of macOS Sierra (with Python 2.7 downloaded from the Python.org website) and when I try to run the code I consistently get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pong.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
```

I have done some research on the error and the only sites that came up with a google search seemed to be in German. I don't suppose anyone would be able to advise on why I'm getting this error with the pygame module and how to fix it? I can provide the source code if it's needed, but from my (admittedly limited) understanding the error lies in the imported pygame module?

Edit: If I remove the `from pygame.base import *` from the file mentioned in the error I get the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pong.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from pygame.constants import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/pygame/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from pygame.rect import Rect
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
```

Comment: what happens when you remove `from pygame.base import *`?

Comment: I get another error, one moment, I'll update the question with it

Comment: How did you install pygame? This Gist might be useful troubleshooting your error: https://gist.github.com/audreyr/5943575

Comment: I installed it using pip install pygame

Comment: Maube try and install pygame from the installer?